# Joining two tables on different servers

Tags: php, database, join, windows-server-2003

we have two databases on two different servers(both Server 2003) - I will call them A server and B server. What we need to do here is joining a table on A server and another table on B together. Using php, we could successfully extract data from the table on A server... but having a trouble with joining this with another table on B server (and vice versa).

The server we will mainly use is A server. Can this joining be done using php functions & queries only? or Is there something we have to do on A server to connect to B server?

Comment: *there something we have to do on A server to connect to B server*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to be to pull the filtering data from server B, save it in a listy variable of some sort, and then build your SQL query for pulling the data from server A along with a `where COLUMN_X in ( FILTER_FROM_B )`.

Without knowing more about your table structures and how you're trying to join them, I can't really give you a more specific answer.